# server-side git hook to automatically cherry-pick one branch to another post-merge

Tags: git, merge, hook

We often push some commit into branch B, and after a successfull merge through Pull Request, we cherry pick the merged commit into branch A and merge it there with the created tag #num.
How can I create a git hook that will automagically cherry pick a successfully merged commit from branch B to branch A?

- Can I condition it on some words in the commit message? (e.g. "(some commit message) | CP"
- Can the git hook also auto merge if possible?

This is my first git hook attempt and I am kinda lost.
Thanks!

Comment: You can write hooks in any language you like, provided you control the host on which they'll run. You mention "pull requests" though, so perhaps you *don't* control the host, if it's GitHub or Bitbucket for instance. I would recommend avoiding this path anyway though: a cherry-pick is a form of merging, and merges can have merge conflicts, which will require human resolution.

Comment: I agree, auto-merging can be an issue.
However, If it will just auto-cherry-pick and commit to branch A after a successfull merge to branch B, conditioned on the string "| CP" in the commit message, that'd be AMAZING for me.

Comment: Well, if you're allowed to write your own post-receive hook, write one that, when reference `refs/heads/X` is updated for some chosen branch name `X`, scans through the new commits that were just added to branch `X`, if any such commits were added. If they have the desired string in them, invoke something to do the cherry-picking. If you *can't* write a post-receive hook, look into GitHub Actions: perhaps you can have an action triggered by a GitHub update. In fact, that may be easier anyway—but I have not written GitHub actions myself.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs @torek! I can definitely write my own post-receive hook. What you offered sounds legit, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: OK. Note that writing *pre- and post-receive* hooks is particularly tricky. You might want to look at some samples. I have a few, e.g., http://web.torek.net/torek/git/pre-receive.sh.txt (assumes pre-SHA256 Git).